# Django Unit Test fails project-wide but passes app-wide

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10.

I have a project with several apps and dozens of unit tests.  We've recently run into a little issue using the `@override_settings` decorator.

Here is some code:

```
@override_settings(MEDIA_URL='/test/media/')
    def test_get_content_dict(self):
        self.assertEqual(
                self.offer.get_content_dict(),
                { 'some stuff': some stuff }
```

When tests are run at the app level everything passes.

```
python manage.py test my_app --settings=proton.settings.test
```

But when we run at the project level it fails.

```
python manage.py test --settings=proton.settings.test
```

It's failing due to `some stuff` using `/test/media` but the model method `offer.get_contect_dict()` using `/media`, which is our actual `MEDIA_URL`.

We can change the `MEDIA_URL` in our `settings/test.py` file, but that would require all tests to use `/test/media` (which might be a good idea anyway).

Clearly the problem is in Django's `core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage.__init__()` - it sets the `base_url` earlier in the test suite but does not re-instantiate the object after each test (for obvious reasons) so the `@override_settings` doesn't actually do anything.

Is this a bug or is this working as intended?  Any suggestions to an elegant solution other than forcing all unit tests to use `/test/media` by setting our `MEDIA_URL` constant in our `settings/test.py` to `/test/media`?

Comment: I agree that it might be a good idea just to have all test code run against `/test/media`.  Otherwise, maybe `get_content_dict` could accept a `base_url` kwarg?

Comment: @dokkaebi We decided to go with changing the `MEDIA_URL = /test/media` in the `settings/test.py` file and force all tests to use that value.  Although it's a simple work-around I don't feel it should have been necessary.  After all, what good is `@override_settings` if it can't actually override settings?